# How to display geographic map using dojo 1.9

Tags: java, html, jsp, dojo, openlayers

I have a specific requirement where i have to simple geographic map using dojo 1.9. I downloaded the openlayer.js from openlayer site but still when i run the page, nothing is displayed.  Would appreciate if anyone can help me with what is missing from my end. Please find the below code.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../dijit/themes/dijit.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css">
<title>Map</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../dijit/themes/tundra/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OpenLayers map inside a Dojo container:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js'></script>
        <script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.12/OpenLayers.js'></script>
        <style type='text/css'>
        html,body,#border,#map { margin:0; width:100%; height:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class='claro'>
        <div id='border' data-dojo-type='dijit/layout/BorderContainer'>
            <div data-dojo-type='dijit/layout/ContentPane' data-dojo-props='region:"center"'>
                <div id='map'></div>
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type='dijit/layout/ContentPane' data-dojo-props='region:"trailing"'>
                Just an example
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        require(['dojo/ready', 'dojo/parser'], function (ready, Parser) {
            ready(function () {
                Parser.parse().then(function () {
                    var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
                        div:'map',
                        displayProjection:new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'),
                        projection:new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913')
                    });
                    map.addLayer(
                        new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM()
                    );
                    map.setCenter(
                        new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0),
                        2
                    );
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The 100% width and height expand everything to fill the viewport.  While you do not need to expand to 100%, you do need to set dimensions on these elements.